# Colocar URL en un campo de datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

¿Cómo se podría colocar una url en un campo especifico de un DataTable? Supongamos por ejemplo que tengo una tabla donde muestro los datos personales de una persona y quiero que el campo con su dirección sea clickeable y me dirija a un enlace especifico. Por el momento logre que se muestre la información y se ordene de la siguiente manera:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("tr:odd").css("background-color", "#fff"); // filas impares
    $("tr:even").css("background-color", "#dddddd"); // filas pares
    $('#mitabla').DataTable({

        "columns": [ //ANCHO
            {
                "width": "5%"
            }, //nombres
            {
                "width": "5%"
            }, //apellidos
            {
                "width": "5%"
            }, //cedula
            {
                "width": "5%"
            }, //telefono
            {
                "visible": false,
                "width": "11%"
            }, //ID
            {
                "width": "5%"
            }, //acciones
        ],

        "order": [
            [0, "asc"]
        ],
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "server_process.php",

        "dom": "<'row'<'col-sm-3'l><'col-sm-6 text-center'B><'col-sm-3'f>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-12'tr>>" +
            "<'row'<'col-sm-5'i><'col-sm-7'p>>",

        "language": {

            "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros por pagina",
            "info": "Mostrando pagina _PAGE_ de _PAGES_",
            "infoEmpty": "No hay registros disponibles",
            "infoFiltered": "(filtrada de _MAX_ registros)",
            "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "processing": "Procesando...",
            "search": "Buscar:",
            "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron registros coincidentes",

            "buttons": {
                "colvis": "OCULTAR COLUMNAS",
            },


            "paginate": {
                "next": "Siguiente",
                "previous": "Anterior"
            }

        },

        buttons: [
            'colvis'
        ],

        columnDefs: [{
            visible: false
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes usar el parámetro [`columnDefs`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs#Description) que permite establecer las propiedades con las que se van a inicializar una o más columnas en la tabla.

Se debe especificar la propiedad [`targets`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs.targets) para indicar cuales son las columnas a las que se le van a aplicar lo que definamos. Pudiendo tomar los argumentos:

- 0 o un entero positivo: es el índice de la columna empezando por la izquierda
- un entero negativo: es el índice de la columna empezando por la derecha
- una cadena: es la clase que posee el encabezado `<th>` de una columna
- la cadena `_all`: todas las columnas (por defecto)

También la propiedad [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) que se encarga de renderizar (o darle formato a) los datos que se usan en la tabla. Puede modificar los datos de origen mediante diferentes operaciones, pasandole como argumento una función que va ser ejecutada y que devolverá el valor a usar. Los parámetros de la función son:

- `data`: los datos de la celda
- `type`
- `row`: los datos de la fila
- `meta`: información adicional sobre la celda (índice de la fila, índice de la columna, etc)

**Ejemplo:**

En este caso se crea un enlace utilizando los datos de la celda y se lo aplica a la segunda columna (la primera tiene el índice 0).

```
$('#tabla').dataTable( {
  "columnDefs": [ {
    "targets": +1,
    "data": "perfil",
    "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
      return '<a href=/perfil/"' + data + '">Perfil</a>';
    }
  } ]
} );
```